# Scope related error in pandas: Unbound local error

Tags: python, pandas, scope

I want to build a URL-shortener which should work as follows:

- shortener saves the original URL typed in by user, the automatically generated numeric ID of the original URL and the base 62-encoded version of the numeric ID.
- with each new entered original URL, those 3 types of information are saved into a pandas data frame as columns;
- the data frame is empty in the beginning; when the first row is inserted, a random numeric ID is generated; the IDs of following rows are incremented by 1
- the process of insertion should have following logic:

1. User gets asks for input (the original URL)
2. a check is conducted, whether this URL is already contained in the database; if it is, the user gets asked to enter a new URL
3. if the URL is not contained in the database yet, the script checks if there are other entries in the database yet
4. if there are no entries, the entered URL gets inserted into the data frame with a randomly generated ID (which is used as the index of the data frame) and the encoded ID
5. if there are other entries available, the entered Url gets inserted into the data frame with an ID that is the last available ID in the data frame + 1

What I want to achieve is to operate on the same data frame without creating copies of the data frame with each new entry. So the main function should each time receive the same data frame and update it with new rows. However, when I execute the code below, and the script gets to the point of executing the line

database = database.append(row)

in the update_database-function, I get the following error:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'database' referenced before assignment

This seems strange, because the variable database is defined on the global scope right on top of the main function, so each function within the main function should have access to it. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import string
import random


#create the 62-base for encoding
digits = [str(i) for i in list(np.arange(0,10))]
letters_upper = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
letters_lower = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
base_62 = digits + letters_upper + letters_lower

#create the empty database with ID as index
database = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['ID', 'URL_long', 'URL_short']).set_index("ID")


#create the 62-base encoded version of the ID
def encode_id(num,base, base_size):
    result = []
    while divmod(num,base_size) != (0,0):
        el = base[divmod(num,base_size)[1]]
        result.append(el)
        num = divmod(num,base_size)[0]
    result.reverse()
    return "".join(result)


def main(df): 
    
    database = df
    
    #asks user for input
    def user_input():
        print("exec user_input")
        return input("Enter your URL: ")

    #if the entered URL is not in the data frame yet, inserts the URL with ID and encoded ID
    def update_database(passed_input_value):
        print("exec_update_database")
        #executes if the data frame is empty
        if len(database) == 0:
            first_id = int("".join(random.sample(string.digits,7)))
            row = pd.Series({"URL_long": passed_input_value, "URL_short": encode_id(first_id,base_62,62)})
            row.name = first_id
        #executes if the data frame already has entries
        else:
            last_id_incr = int(df.index[-1]+1)
            row = pd.Series({"URL_long": passed_input_value, "URL_short": encode_id(last_id_incr,base_62,62)})
            row.name = last_id_incr
        #appends the created row to the data frame
        #this is where the error happens
        database = database.append(row)
    
   #checks if the entered URL is already in the data frame 
   #if it is, redirects to the beginning of the process 
   #if it's not, passes the value of the input to the update-function and executes it
    def check_duplicates():
        print("exec_check_duplicates")
        input_value = user_input()
        if input_value in database["URL_long"].unique():
            url_available = database[database["URL_long"]==input_value].iloc[0]['URL_short']
            print(f"URL already shortened: {url_available}.")
            check_duplicates()
        else:
            update_database(input_value)
                  
    
    check_duplicates()
    return database

main(database)
```

Comment: You need to add `global database` as the first line of your `update_database` function.

Comment: If a value is assigned to a variable anywhere in a function, this variable is seen as local, regardless if a variable with same name in an outer scope exists. You must explicitly declare the variable as "nonlocal" or "global" to avoid that.

Comment: Great, many thanks. This seems to eliminate the error. However, when the return statement is executed at the end of the main function (right after check_duplicates()), the output returns an empty data frame. But when I execute a print statement on a new line in a Jupiter notebook "print (database)", I get the updated data frame. Could you explain?